# Disable Progress bar percentual

Tags: windows, windows-10, progress

How do I disable progress bar percent - Windows 10?

I tried:

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%Deskjet" "C:\temp\DANFE.pdf"
```

Comment: Try adding `dNoCancel`

Comment: Thank you David, it works perfectly!

Comment: Great! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I disable progress bar percent?

You can use the `dNoCancel` option on Windows:

> `-dNoCancel`
>
> **Hides the progress dialog, which shows the percent of the document page already processed** and also provides a cancel button. This
>   option is useful if GS is intended to print pages in the background,
>   without any user intervention.

Source [Details of Ghostscript output devices](https://www.biu.ac.il/os_site/documentation/gs/Devices.htm)